# Dynamic script not loading on history.go()

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I have a static html page that I cannot edit- it does refer to a js file though, so what I do is redirect that url request on my IIS server to my js file- where I dynamically inject jQuery so I can use it.  Here's the code I use to insert jQuery:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = jqueryReady;              //most browsers
script.onreadystatechange = function () { //ie
    if ( this.readyState == 'complete' ) {
        jqueryReady();
    }
};
```

This works great except in one specific case- if I call history.go() on the page when the browser is IE and the page is being served up from an internal web server.  Hitting F5 also does not reload the page properly.  I have to put the cursor in the address bar and hit enter to get it to load right.

Edit:  Forgot to mention the obvious- I have a breakpoint in the jqueryReady() function- and it never gets hit- which is where the problem lies...

It works fine from IE in my dev environment if I serve the page up and then fire history.go() (with a button click).  It works with chrome, haven't tested firefox.

So is there an alternative to history.go() to fire a 'true' page reload like what hitting enter in the address bar?

This is also a HUGE page - 6000 lines of html (I didn't write it) and jQuery and all javascript is being loaded in the head- I know you are supposed to load js stuff at the end of the page.  Maybe this is related?  It feels like a timing issue...

Anyone have any thoughts as to things to check/try?  Or know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Okay found it... so the solution was [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Bottom line is the code I was using isn't correct, this is the recommended approach to dynamically insert a script into a document and then handle the ready event:

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.src = "/reporter/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js";
if ( script.addEventListener ) {
    script.addEventListener( "load", jqueryReady, false );
}
else if ( script.readyState ) {
    script.onreadystatechange = jqueryReady;
}
document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[0].appendChild( script );
```

Additionally, I needed to check if jQuery was loaded in my jqueryReady function:

```
function jqueryReady() {
    // Check if jQuery exists
    if ( typeof jQuery != 'undefined' ) {
        // do stuff like $(document).ready()
    }
}
```

This seemed to work in all cases that I could find.

Hope this helps someone else!